# Where can i get dll's to deploying app in Qt on windows?

Tags: windows, qt, dll, runtime

My app successfully runs from Qt Creator, but in explorer it alarms missing dll's and so. I copied QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll in .exe containing directory, but it abuses on something related with vs runtime!
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEjh6.png)

(also it is question which QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll are proper, because there some versions with different sizes and i think their combinations may cause the error)

What can i do?

Comment: If you're running a debug version of your Qt application, then you'll have to use dll's ending with 'd'. For Ex. QtCore4d.dll, QtGui4d.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find out what DLL files are needed by your Qt application is the following:

1. Start the application from Qt Creator.
2. Open [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (by Microsoft) and select your application process from the list.
3. Click View->Lower pane view->DLLs to see what DLLs are being used by your application.

The DLL view shows also the paths of the DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

this problem has nothing to do with the dependencies of the application. It looks like your application is statically embedding (containing) the C-runtime library, while (at the same time) some dependencies of this application use another type of binding with the C-Runtime library.